# Is it possible to independently drag & drop multiple objects on a FabricJS canvas at the same time?

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm working on a touch-based app w/ [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/). Out of the box, the drag & drop support is phenomenal. Unfortunately, you can only drag one object at a time - the rest of the canvas is essentially 'locked' until the current object's drag has ended.

Is it possible to concurrently drag more than one object at a time? How could it be accomplished? My use case is this: imagine a canvas with multiple puzzle pieces you can touch/drag around. I'd like to be able to independently touch and drag at least 2 pieces (each with a different finger) at the same time.

I'm using the standard drag event handler. I don't see any obvious way to accomplish this.

```
canvas.on('object:moving', function (e) { ... });
```

Comment: Have you thought about asking the author on github, or raising a feature request? My uneducated guess would be that it's technically possible, but has not yet been implemented in Fabric.

Comment: I did tweet at the author several days ago. Going through github is a good suggestion, though.

Comment: @KurtSchindler yes, it should be possible via gestures module, but IIRC it might need some tweaking (won't work outside of the box, unlike single-touch gestures)

Comment: Any possibility of implementing this soonish in fabric.js @kangax ?

Answer (score 0):

You can group your objects.

```
var mygroup = new fabric.Group([ obj1, obj2, obj3 ], { left: 200, top: 200 });
canvas.add(group);
```

You can pre-group your objects or let user select which objects to group. A group can be draggable alltogether.

This method works after version 1.3.12

Comment: I'm aware of this, but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm trying to independently move >=2 objects in different directions at once, using >=2 fingers on a touch screen. Grouping would move them all in the same direction based on the position a single drag.

Comment: Can you add this to your question? Touch screen is not the first thing comes to mind :)